kafka deployment with helm chart over EKS cluster not able to produce or consume data getting timeout issue in kafka producer side
Deploying the kafka service in AWS EKS cluster using helm chart. kafka is deployed properly able to create topics also but when I am creating producer and providing some messages kafka consumer is not able to consume the data.
Getting timeout issue at producer end.
Even when I install the same kafka helm chart in Azure AKS cluster I am able to produce and consume the data.
Below is the error which I am getting.
I have no name!@matrix-kafka-0:/$ kafka-console-producer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:29092 --topic test

hello
hi
[2024-06-18 11:04:22,907] ERROR Error when sending message to topic test with key: null, value: 5 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 2 record(s) for test-0:120000 ms has passed since batch creation
[2024-06-18 11:04:22,915] ERROR Error when sending message to topic test with key: null, value: 2 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 2 record(s) for test-0:120000 ms has passed since batch creation

I have tried to implement same kafka helm chart in Azure AKS cluster and it's working fine.
Please helm here to resolve this issue.
Manish Kushwaha

Consider to ask sys-admin questions (e.g. about installation of pre-made software) on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Issue got resolved.
I have implemented bitnami kafka version 3.6. It's working fine in eks cluster 1.29 version.
